# Why is dispatchGroup.notify called after only the first task has exited?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Why is dispatchGroup.notify called after only the first task has exited?

In the following code the output is as follows:

```
1) Did the other thing 

**2) Did all the things** 

3) Did one thing 

4) done waiting
```

I would expect:

```
1) Did the other thing 

2) Did one thing 

3) done waiting

**4) Did all the things**
```

---

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print("Did all the things")
        }


        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        print("Did one thing")
            dispatchGroup.leave()

        }


        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("Did the other thing")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.wait()
        print("done waiting")

    }
```

---

As a side note if I perform this on the main thread it works as expected.

Comment: Your call to `notify` is too soon. `notify` is called when there are no pending calls to `leave` needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the very minimal Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

> func notify(queue: DispatchQueue, work: DispatchWorkItem)
>   Schedules a work item to be submitted to a queue when a group of **previously** submitted block objects have completed.

In my example above I called **dispatchQueue.notify** *before* I had submitted my blocks to the queue. By updating the code as follows, I was able to get the expected behavior.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()



        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        print("Did one thing")
            dispatchGroup.leave()

        }


        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("Did the other thing")
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print("Did all the things")
        }

        dispatchGroup.wait()
        print("done waiting")

    }
```

Comment: Typically there is no reason to call both `notify` and `wait`. `notify` is the async interface. `wait` is the sync interface.

Comment: Also note that the tool you want here is `dispatchQueue.async(group: ...)` rather than calling `enter` and `leave` by hand each time. (The documentation for this used to be much more extensive; it has substantially regressed in recent years. As a rule, looking for ObjC documentation that is marked as "out of date" is your best documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html